# Fastest way to load multiple numpy arrays into spark rdd?

Tags: numpy, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to Spark. In my application, I would like to create an RDD from many numpy arrays. Each numpy array is (10,000, 5,000). Currently, I'm trying the following:

```
rdd_list = []
for np_array in np_arrays:
    pandas_df = pd.DataFrame(np_array)
    spark_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pandas_df)  ##SLOW STEP
    rdd_list.append(spark_df.rdd)
big_rdd = sc.union(rdd_list)
```

All of the steps are fast, except converting the Pandas dataframe to Spark dataframe is very slow. If I use a subset of the numpy array, such (10,000, 500), it takes a couple minutes to convert it to a Spark dataframe. But if I use the full numpy array (10,000, 5,000), it just hangs.

Is there anything I can do to speed up my workflow? Or should I be doing this in a completely different way? (FYI, I'm kind of stuck with the initial numpy arrays.)

Comment: Have you tried converting them to csv files (no headers) and then using wildcards to read the rdd as a whole?

Answer (score 0):

For my application I had used the class `ArrayRDD` from the [sparkit-learn](https://github.com/lensacom/sparkit-learn) project for loading numpy arrays into spark RDDs. I had no complaints but your mileage may vary.